# Transfer a checked item to bottom of the list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a todo-list using jquery(not angularjs), add items to the list and if a item is checked than transfer the item to bottom of the list. How would I do that using jQuery?

I appreciate you help.

I have started with the following code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test02.css"/>

       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test02.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <h1>Todos</h1>
            <input type="text"  id="new-text" placeholder="What do you need to do?">
            <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">

            <ul id="todolist"></ul>


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
            $("#add").on('click', addListItem);
            $(document).on('click', '.done', finishItem);
        });

    function addListItem() {
        if($("#new-text").val() !== ''){
            var text = $("#new-text").val();
            $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="done"/>' + text + '</li>');
            $("#new-text").val('');
            }
        }                          
    }

    function finishItem() {
        if( $(this).parent().css('textDecoration') !== 'line-through' ){
            $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');       
        }else{
            $(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'none');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you had a redundant curly bracket in your JS code after the "addLastItem" function.

I have some more recommendations for your code:

- Save all jQuery elements in a variable to speed up your page:
- ```
  var $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.parent();
  ```
- Instead of using the "text-decoration" attribute to determine weather a list element is "done" ...

  ```
  if ($(this).parent().css('textDecoration') !== 'line-through' ) { ... }
  ```

  ... use the "checked" property of the checkbox:

  ```
  if ($this.is(':checked')) { ... }
  ```

---

In order to move the checked item to the bottom of the list you can use jQuery's ".append()" function.

**Check it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m639n0v/1/).** I also used the "prepend" function to move the element to the top of the list if it gets unchecked.

```
function finishItem() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent();

    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $parent.css('textDecoration', 'line-through');

        $todolist.append($parent);

    } else {
        $parent.css('textDecoration', 'none');

        $todolist.prepend($parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I see that you're still an active community member so I'm hoping you can help. I'm using your method, but I'm running into the issue where when I check or uncheck an item in the middle or bottom of my list the window scrolls upward, sometimes all the way back to the top. How can I prevent the scrolling? Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caffeinatedcoder/6krn9sb2/) to show how I've adapted your code and to see it in action.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with floating. You can either add `clear: right` to each list item or remove the floating of `.name` completely: https://jsfiddle.net/664ucbtx/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.appendTo("#todolist")` will move the current element to the end of the list.

So where you have `$(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through');`

change it to `$(this).parent().css('textDecoration', 'line-through').appendTo("#todolist");`